# Could you show me a site where ajax-driven country-region-city drop down list is used?

Tags: ajax

Could you show me a site where ajax-driven country-region-city drop down list is used?

Comment: Do you need just a working demo, or a form in production ?

Answer (score 0):

[hotmail](http://Hotmail.com) seems to be using one for their [signup](https://signup.live.com/), it does update the city dropdown depending on the country without refreshing the page, but I don't know if they're using AJAX or something else.

Answer (score 0):

[here's](http://www.ajaxdeveloper.ca/Examples.html) a good example ..

Altho the demo seems to be slightly broken there's example code there that you can make work, I'll bet

Comment: i don't need examples, only forms in production